# A confusion regarding the proof of "Lebesgue outer measure of an interval is its length."

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

I have understood the overall proof but I have a confusion at the very beginning of the proof: Usually in the first case of a closed interval, say $[a,b]$, we find that for each $\varepsilon>0,$ $\exists$ an open interval $(a-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon)$ which contains $[a,b]$. And then it is written that:

$m^*([a,b])\le \ell((a-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon))=b-a+2\varepsilon.\tag1$

Herein lies my confusion. I mean, here $[a,b]\subseteq(a-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon).$ So we could use the *monotonicity* property of outer measure, but then also we would have outer measure of that open interval on right in $(1).$ Instead, in $(1),$ the length of that open interval has been taken. Also, no open covering of $[a,b]$ has been taken so that we could use the sum of length of those open intervals on right in $(1).$

Basically, my question is: How could we justify the inequality $(1)$? Please shed some light about the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The collection $\{ (a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)\}$ with a single member is an open covering of $[a,b]$ and the sum of the lengths is $b-a+ 2\epsilon$. Recall the definition of outer measure.

Comment: @RRL Ah! Yes. I didn't think that way only that a single element class also can form a cover. I feel dumb now. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Incidentally, a reasonable question (to me) is why we can't just show that the outer measure of $[a,b]$ equals $b-a$ by letting $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ for single coverings of this type. The problem is how do we know we can't get SMALLER sums by using more than one open interval in our coverings? It seems obvious we can't, but this "obviousness" is based on our intuitive understanding of what **should happen**, which might not (until we know by proving otherwise) be the way our "coverings definition of measure" actually works. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3089026/13130).